# Why we call the signal function in the start of the linux c program?

Tags: c, linux

The program is very simple, I have a handler function named `fintr()` and the program is:

```
void fintr();

int main() {
    int i;
    signal(SIGINT,fintr);
    while(1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    return 0;
}

void fintr() {
    printf("signal received");
    exit(1);
}
```

Can I put `signal(SIGINT,fintr);` at the end of the function `main()`? And why do we have to put it in the beginning of `main()`?

Comment: `printf()` is not async-safe, AFAIK. Your program is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it at the end means it will come after the `while (1) ...` loop, so no, you can't put it in the end, because it would never be executed.

Also, pay attention to the code you place inside signal handlers: It is not safe to call `printf()` inside a signal handler.